# Fix radgrid height with paging

Tags: radgrid

How to fix the size of radgrid irrespective of records.
I set the paging with pagesize = 5.
When radgrid has 5 rows its height will be ok.
If the grid has 2 rows its fits to the 2 rows height.
How to fix the radgrid height.
I think you got my problem.
I'm doing like this in page_load
radgrid.Height=Unit.Pixel(200);

Hi can anyone answer my question..?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-to-set-the-radgrid-to-auto-resize-the-height-to-fit-the-page-size.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the Databound() event handler, check for the number of records.

```
 int c = RadGrid1.Items.Count()
```

Then try your:

```
 RadGrid1.Height = Unit.Pixel( Whatever you want ) * c;
```

Answer (score 0):

set the scroll height instead of setting the height. This makes sure that the whole data area height is maintained.

```
RadGrid1.ClientSettings.Scrolling.ScrollHeight = Unit.Pixel(200);
```

This article may help as well.
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-height-vs-scrollheight.html